# How to rearrange some elements as a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, element

I want to rearrange some elements as a date frame. elements as follows:

```
  code<-000586
  t<-2013-12-28
  price<-10.23
  change<-2.56
```

I want use these elements form a data frame like this

```
 code      t       price    change 
 000586 2013-12-28 10.23     2.56
```

```
   > t1=2013-12-27
   > head(mydat)
     dm     sc  date      code
14 000586   sz 2013-12-27 000586.sz
15 000616   sz 2013-12-26 000616.sz
16 300295   sz 2013-12-25 300295.sz
17 000968   sz 2013-12-23 000968.sz
18 600023   sh 2013-12-19 600023.sh
20 600855   sh 2013-12-18 600855.sh

  >code<-mydat[1,1]
 > t1<-mydat[1,3]
  > class(wk)
    [1] "list"
  >wk
   $ErrorCode
   [1] 0

  $Data
  DATETIME    OPEN    CLOSE HIGH   PCT_CHG
 1 2013-12-27  12.2   12.5  127    0.25
 2 2013-12-30  12.0  12.4  12.6    0.26
 3 2013-12-31  11.3   11.2 11.5    2.1
 4 2014-01-02  11.1   11.4  11.5   0.2
 5 2014-01-03  11.4  11.5  11.6    0.32
 6 2014-01-06  10.2   10.4  10.6   0.34

 $Code
 [1] "000686"
 wk<-wk[2]$Data
 lo1<-wk[2,2])
 lo2<-wk[3,2]
 lo3<-wk[4,2]
 lc1<-wk[2,3]
 lc2<-wk[3,3]
 lc3<-wk[4,3]
```

I use the code m1<-c(code,t1,lo1=lo1,lo2=lo3,lo3) to form a data frame, but does not work; t1 changes to be not date value.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- data.frame(code="000586", t=as.Date("2013-12-28"), price=10.23, change=2.56)
```

will get you what you want, but if you are curious as to how to build such a data structure, be very wary of the analysis code you plan on cutting & pasting to arrive at an answer. This is really basic R.

Comment: thanks for your help. but it cannot help me . The value to these elements is the result of a middle compute process.i can write it by hand.

Comment: then, it would help if you provided a larger code sample so folks could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

i have got the solutions. before

```
 m1<-c(code,t1,lo1=lo1,lo2=lo3,lo3)
```

i add the code

t1<-as.character(t1)

then it works.